# Using Factual API for Android

Tags: android, barcode, scanning, factual

I want to get product info by using barcode and want to query it in https://www.factual.com. How can I use factual API for Android and how I configure it ?

Answer (score 0):

Start from [factual's developer website](http://developer.factual.com/) .

Comment: Is there any example ? So that i can use it as a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up the get start in the documentation,

Here is the link: http://developer.factual.com/get-started/

Do it step by step, and on the step 4, you will get some example you need to try it out.

Comment: Yes i read it but i am facing difficulty at second step [Download and install a Factual API driver for the language you want to use. We have the following drivers available*:
Android].  I want to install it for android but dnt know how i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Go This page and download the relevant example

http://developer.factual.com/examples/

and start exploring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use http call to query the factual.com tables.
Here are some http examples you have to call on your code: (after you have your api key)

http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?q=shampoo

[http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?q=shampoo&filters={"brand":"pantene"}](http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?q=shampoo&filters=%7B%22brand%22:%22pantene%22%7D)

[http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?filters={"upc":"052000131512"}](http://api.v3.factual.com/t/products-cpg?filters=%7B%22upc%22:%22052000131512%22%7D)

You can look on this page for more examples:

http://developer.factual.com/working-with-factual-products/

I think you are looking for this table field: **upc_e** = The UPC-E barcode used for identifying products. 8-digits in length.

The product table schema is here:

http://www.factual.com/data/t/products-cpg/schema

Comment: I need help in  [Download and install a Factual API driver for the language you want to use. We have the following drivers available*: Android]. How to install it for Android ? How i do this step?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by placing php driver of factual in root directory of WAMP server.Instead of android, i use php driver. Now i am sending barcode form android device to WAMP (server) PHP driver.